# How to fix the following error during an update?

Tags: updates, software-sources

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Does the error persist if you try again?

Comment: Probably a conenction error. You should try again.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of this error message it seems you either have no working internet connection, or the site was unavailable. You should verify you have a working internet connection and try again.

EDIT: As pointed out by steeldriver in the comment below, 12.10 is no longer supported!

Comment: The repository is unavailable because Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) is no longer a supported release

Comment: @steeldriver Ah well spotted indeed! I will change my answer to reflect this.